# Clarification of Answers given in Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 1-24

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, arithmetic

I am self-studying Spivak's Calculus.

In Chapter 1, Question 24, $a_1 + \ldots + a_n$ is defined as $a_1 + (a_2 + (a_3 + \ldots + (a_{n-2} + (a_{n-1} + a_n))) \ldots )$.

In part (a), we are asked to proof that $(a_1 + \ldots + a_k) + a_{k+1} = a_1 + \ldots + a_{k+1}$. The hint given was to use induction.

In the answers, it is written that:

\begin{align} (a_1 + \ldots + a_{k+1}) + a_{k+2} &= [(a_1 + \ldots + a_{k}) + a_{k+1}] + a_{k+2} \\ &= (a_1 + \ldots + a_{k}) + (a_{k+1} + a_{k+2}) \\ &= a_1 + \ldots + a_{k} + (a_{k+1} + a_{k+2}) \\ &= a_1 \ldots + a_{k+2} \end{align}

For the first and third equality, it is true because the equation holds for $k$. For the second equality, it is true because $a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$. However, for the last equality, it is written that it is true by the definition of $a_1 + \ldots + a_{k+2}$.

I do not understand how the last inequality is derived from the definition. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To make it more clear, let say for the moment that $b=a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}$. Then on your third line you have $a_1+\cdots +a_k+b$ which is by definition is $a_1+\left(a_2+\cdots \left(a_{k-1}+(a_k+b)\right)\right)$ which is the same as
$a_1+\left(a_2+\cdots \left(a_{k-1}+(a_k+(a_{k+1}+a_{k+2})\right)\right)$ but this is the very definition of $a_1+\cdots +a_{k+2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would then ask why does $a_1 + \ldots + a_n$ have to be added from the back and not, say, from the front? Or should the logic be that is could be added in both ways?

Comment: Ok I see it now, treating $b = a_{k+1} + a_{k+2}$, applying Spivak's definition, and finally expanding $b$ would result in the equality. Thanks!